# Stock options when using a bundled configurable product

Tags: magento

In a magento store we have a product configured as follows:

- Shoe offer (bundled product)

  - Black shoe ( configurable product )

    - Size 1 (simple product)
    - Size 2  (simple product)

So we have a bundled product which consists out of a configurable product who has various simple products.

What we expect to happen is that when someone orders a single Size 2 shoe via the shoe offer that the stock of the 'Size 2' is reduced by one. This doesn't happen. We configured all products to manage stock, so we are wondering if this is possible or that we have to come up with our own solution.

We are using Magento 1.6.0.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this an other way by removing the configurable product out of the configuration. So the bundle product now directly has the simple products embedded and that way the inventory will be managed correctly.